# How do i run a executable springboot jar by setting a profile?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-profiles

I am trying to set the profile as dev,but the spring boot app does not start in dev profile.`No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default`.

i am running with the command :java -jar myapp.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev

Answer (score 2):

I was able to run it with the following:
java -jar myapp.jar **--**spring.profiles.active=dev

Note that it needs to be -- and elimination of D

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way to execute

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar myapp.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important that the -D parameters are before your application.jar otherwise they are not recognized.

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev app.jar
or
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=dev
```